# Wordpress "read more" instead of full post on blog homepage through child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the blog: http://radutanasescu.ro/

This is the theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/responsive/

The child theme: http://cyberchimps.com/guide/child-theme-example/

And looking here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More, I tried to convince the theme to show excerpts instead of full posts on the Homepage by typing this in the child themes `function.php` file like this:

```
<?php 
    function new_excerpt_more($more) {
        //die('no yolo :(');
        global $post;
        return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>';
    }
    function child_theme_setup() {
        //die('yolo works');
        // Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link
        add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
    }
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'child_theme_setup' );
?>
```

It's obviously not working because I'm a php noob, if un-commented `die('yolo works');` works and `die('no yolo :(');` doesn't.

Comment: Out of interest would you be happy editing the homepage template? This to me would be the far more logical solution. The joy of a child theme is that you can edit bits of the parent theme to suit your needs.

I also think that what you are trying to do will not work due to what is being shown on the homepage as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow :) from what I've read, if I want to maintain the ability to upgrade the "Responsive" theme, I must not edit it, that is what the child theme is for, is it not?

Comment: try using `pre_get_post` hook, that may help you.

Comment: Can you show me how that would look in my code? I'm not familiar with wordpress or php at this level :)